# Infertility=Useless?

Tags: children, family, child-adoption

I’ve read on this sight that it is a requirement that all people are to have children to keep our communities flowing. But what if one is incapable of conceiving for whatever reasons aside from using birth control? Are they no longer useful? Are they worthless?
In this religion it is viewed as crucial and top tier to have a family saying how extraordinaire it is to have them to the point where it’s as if not being able to have children makes them a weak person, whom have no purpose in life.

Is that the case for those who do not want and/or cannot have children?

Comment: Just because having a family is praised a lot doesn't mean it is the only purpose in life. You should be able to figure out what the main purpose of life is in Islam. Hint: It's not having children.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. Please share a link to the post saying that having children is a requirement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never ever read in Quran or Hadith saying that an infertile woman is useless.
Infertile means a woman cannot have a child, it means Allah decided to not give them child for a certain period of her life or her whole life. It doesn't mean she is considered useless in Islam.

Allah himself says he will test us by taking valuables from us. Children are the couples' most valued.

Prophet Ibrahim's Wife was infertile for a very long period.
Prophet Muhammed's many wives didn't have a single children, Ayesha didn't have a child.
Prophet Zakariyah didn't have children for a long time.

So Islam never viewed children as a qualification for anything. Many people who don't know anything complains and accuses women for not having children. It's the people's fault for not knowing the good.

**Islam is not responsible for what Muslims do. So don't judge Islam because of some muslim's behavior**